# /etc/security/limits.conf for setting program limits in Linux

Tags: linux, pam

I have the following inside /etc/security/limits.conf
(I have specified root separately because * will not include it.)

```
user2      -     core          unlimited
*          -     core          0
root       -     core          0
*          -     rss           512000
root       -     rss           512000
*          -     nproc         100
root       -     nproc         100
*          -     maxlogins     1
root       -     maxlogins     1
```

I run a program as user2 (./programname) but /proc/3498/limits says cores are disabled:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    0                    bytes     
Max resident set          524288000            524288000            bytes     
Max processes             100                  100                  processes 
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       14001                14001                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Both ulimit -Sa and ulimit -Ha output that cores are disabled:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 14001
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 512000
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 100
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Why are cores disabled ?

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "I run a program as user2"? Perhaps you are expecting these limits to magically impose themselves -- you have to run some program that imposes them.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible there's some profile somewhere that is setting user2's shell with `ulimit -c 0`? When I start bash without `ulimit -c` and check a process that I start I see this:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
```

But when I `ulimit -c 0` and run a process, I see this:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max core file size        0                    0                    bytes
```

Have you tried setting `ulimit -c unlimited` at the end of user2's shell rc file?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following order:

```
*          -     core          0
user2      -     core          unlimited
root       -     core          0
```

At least for some settings the order matters in limits.conf.

Comment: modified to your suggestion, restarted, but continues with same problem.